# "npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher" when I tried to install pm2 in virtual hosting Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, deployment, pm2

I'm getting above the error whenever I try to install pm2 in Ubuntu in my virtual hosting machine.

Command:

```
sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
```

Error:

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
```

What should I do?

Comment: You're getting that _warning_, it's not an error. Unless you actually maintain PM2 or whatever transitive dependency brings that package in, there's nothing you can do. https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5134

Comment: ok thank you jonrshrpe 

Answer (score 1):

you can try install the new version

```
npm install uuid@7.0.3 -g
```

Comment: if if does not work .you can find your node_modules folder.and the ln to the path  
ln -s /root/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 /usr/local/bin/pm2